# Breaking granite in the sandbox custom game type?

Tags: dungeons

In Dungeons (PC), how do you break the granite that surrounds the monster dens in the custom sandbox game types?

By granite, I mean the stone that your goblin workers can't burrow through. I can't find any spells or items that allow you to break the stone. Seeing as it's sandbox, there's no quests that trigger them to "become breakable", which is what happened in the single player.

Comment: Tweaked the tag to use the one for the game. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to break the granite for the den to be available, it only has to be "in your area of influence" (the glowing ring that floats around your dungeon). If they are within that border, then you have access to build the pentagram for the monster they house!